Real part of an eigenvalue lies in numerical range
I‘m struggling to prove this Lemma and will be glad to get hints:

If $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n*n}$, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $Re(\lambda)\in\{\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}, x\in\mathbb{R}^n$\ $\{0\}\}$

First I tried to use that $\overline{\lambda}$ is eigenvalue too, but this didn’t work. We now that complex Numerical Range is convex, so we know that real part lies there, but i don’t know how to conclude that there exists real vector
